# html5 : previous/next button to play preceding/succeeding videos

Tags: html5-video

I am new to html5. I have created an html page with video loaded by default. what i need to create is an html page with buttons play/pause,next and previous and an array of videos.while clicking the next button the next video in the array should be loaded, similarly for the previous button.

I has used html5  tag to call the first video(which is loaded on the screen).how can i implement the next and previous button features. how can i create  an array of videos and how can i call them.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<video  id="video1" class="container1" preload="auto"controls="controls" tabindex="0" >
<source id="v1" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" src="videos\mov_bbb.mp4"></source>
<source id="v2" type="video/ogg" codecs="theora, vorbis" src="videos\mov_bbb.ogv"></source>
<source id="v3" type="video/webm" codecs="vp8, vorbis"  src="videos\mov_bbb.webm"></source>
</video>
```

Comment: I have recently worked on a similar code, i didn't need any of the `source` tags, all is managed within JavaScript.

Comment: @Malloc thank you. will change the `source` tag and and set the array within JavaScript. but each of the videos has three formats. if browser change i need to call only one among the video format.At that point increment of index results in the next video in the list. how can i jump to the next video in the list

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting up two buttons and trigger an event that changes the source of the video element. That way you just need one html5 Video element. The javascript code would look like as follow:

```
var player = document.querySelector('#video');
var i = 0;
var back = document.querySelector('#back');
var next = document.querySelector('#next');
var videos = [  // here is your list of videos
    'video1.mp4',
    'video2.mp4',
    '...'
];

back.addEventListener('click',function(){
    player.src = videos[i == 0 ? videos.length-- : i--];
    video.play();
},false);

next.addEventListener('click',function(){
    player.src = videos[i == videos.length-- ? 0 : i++];
    video.play();
},false);

player.src = videos[i];
player.play(); //init the video player
```

Comment: thank you for the immediate reply. i am still working on it. i have three different formats of each video to get support from different browsers. this is how i created the video tag.

Comment: <video  id="video1" class="container1" preload="auto"controls="controls" tabindex="0" >
<source id="v1" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" src="videos\mov_bbb.mp4"></source>
<source id="v2" type="video/ogg" codecs="theora, vorbis" src="videos\mov_bbb.ogv"></source>
<source id="v3" type="video/webm" codecs="vp8, vorbis"  src="videos\mov_bbb.webm"></source>
</video>

Comment: @ sorry, i m a new user in this forum.sorry for the inconvinience caused

Comment: give the id a general name, `video` instead of `video1`, because it's a container for all your videos. For multiple format, in the directory where you put videos, give the same name for each video independently what's its format: `video1.mp4`/`video1.ogv`/`video2.mp4`/`video2.ogv`

Answer (score 0):

in your html video container:

```
<video id='currentVideo'></video>
```

***JavaScript code:***

```
//Global variable for the current video name
var currentVideoName='video1.avi';

var videoList=['video1.avi','video2.mp4','video3.mpg'];
var myVideo = document.getElementById('currentVideo');

var index = videoList.indexOf(window.currentVideoName);

//Next button
myVideo.pause();
myVideo.currentTime=0;
myVideo.src = 'videosDirectory/'+videoList[index+1];
window.currentVideoName=videoList[index+1];
myVideo.play();

//Pause button
myVideo.pause();

//Previous button
myVideo.pause();
myVideo.currentTime=0;
myVideo.src = 'videosDirectory/'+videoList[index-1];
window.currentVideoName=videoList[index-1];
myVideo.play();

//Play button
myVideo.play();
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I am not clear with "currentVideoName='video1.avi'".The video format will change according to the browser .so this can't be set as static right??Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: hmm, i tested with the `mp4` format and it works with `IE9`, `FF` and `Chrome`, you can change `currentVideoName=video1.avi` to `currentVideoName=video1.mp4` and try with all browsers.

Comment: ok. i will give it a try. thank you. will update you with the results

Comment: I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" upon running the script. what is the problem. thanks in advance

Comment: the issue has been fixed by changing videosDirectory\ to videosDirectory/ . The second video gets called from the location but not getting loaded. kindly help me on this. do i need to change the list in which only mp4 format is added

Comment: Try to load it. Before `myVideo.play();`, put: `myVideo.load();`